# Writing API-first app, need authentication model and workflow

Tags: node.js, api, session, express

So I'm making a mobile app, which will use the API I'm writing. The API will be used only by the mobile app, and not by anyone else (maybe I'll allow others with a limited method set?).

The API itself, works except I'm concerned about:
- Security
- It being stateless

I'm using passport.js for user authentication, and a RedisStore for storing user sessions:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 })
}));
```

For api calls that require an authenticated user, I just check if the `req.isAuthenticated()` method is true or not. Pretty standard.

However, my reading and research suggests that API's that reply on sessions are poor design. How do I change that? What is a good, not complicated design for this kind of a model? What should I be doing given my use case? Any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is probably your best bet. It [looks to be straightforward to implement with Passport](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/).

An alternative method is to generate a random token string on login, store it in the database with an expiry time, and require the token to be included in every request in order to validate it.

Comment: From what I read, OAuth is good when you have many clients accessing your app (like Twitter or FB). I would want just my app to do so.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I've suggested an alternative method.

Comment: How secure will it be? I'm doing something similar for password reset process.

Comment: It's secure enough for most needs. It avoids the need to send the password with every request, and it makes it easy to force a client to log in again by deleting the token from the database if required.